# How implement an access token, so I can bypass login page (sailsjs)

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a SailsJS website for which I implemented authentication through a form where user needs to fill in email and password. copied from [ActivityOverloard 2.0 example code](https://github.com/irlnathan/activityoverlord20)

## Login

```
login: function(req, res) {
    console.log("Login hehe!!");
    // Try to look up user using the provided email address
    User.findOne({
      email: req.param('email')
    }, function foundUser(err, user) {
      if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
      if (!user) return res.notFound();

      console.log("found email");

      // Compare password attempt from the form params to the encrypted password
      // from the database (`user.password`)
      require('machinepack-passwords').checkPassword({
        passwordAttempt: req.param('password'),
        encryptedPassword: user.encryptedPassword
      }).exec({

        error: function(err) {
          console.log("There was an error with password");
          return res.negotiate(err);
        },

        // If the password from the form params doesn't checkout w/ the encrypted
        // password from the database...
        incorrect: function() {
          console.log("Password doesn't checkout w/ the encrypted");
          return res.notFound();
        },

        success: function() {
          console.log("Good password");
          var now = new Date();
          User.update(user.id, { online: true, lastLoggedIn: now }, function() {
            // Store user id in the user session
            req.session.me = user.id;

            User.publishUpdate(user.id, {
              online: true,
              id: user.id,
              name: user.name,
              lastLoggedIn: now,
              action: ' has logged in.'
            });

            // All done- let the client know that everything worked.
            return res.ok();
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

my page is protected with login

```
  myPage: function(req, res) {
    if (!req.session.me) {
      return res.view('login'); // not authenticated will take you to the login page
    }

    // It's authenticated, it runs the code below
    // DO SOMETHING
```

Now a very special use case, I need to open my page without user interaction (It can't be through a form) but I still need it to be protected. I'd need to pass some kind of access token.

I understand that passing an "access token" as query param is most probably not a good idea isn't it?

In fact, I don't know how to resolve my problem and allow to access myPage other than a session based authentication through a user interaction via a form ...

It seems to me that I'd need to first get a token programmatically and then open a browse to my page ... I bet there is some best practices to address my problem out there.

Any pointers? may be someone can fill the knowledge gap.

Comment: Have you tried using the default `sails session` mechanism. It uses redis to store the sessions. https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session

Comment: can you be more specific on how?

Comment: I guess you are looking for a Single Sign On style operation. Passport with SAML 2.0 should do the trick for you.

Comment: @Glen I think that is indeed what I may be looking for. I find your suggestion very interesting. I will be reading about **SSO** and SAML 2.0. You may want to add an answer and elaborate a little about what I need to do. I will reward with a bounty

Comment: @zabumba I am heavily involved in development on this topic at the moment, so I will provide some options for you in the answers below. All bounties are welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realisticly speaking, you have multiple options with regards to passwordless or formless logins in node.js/express.js and therefore sails.js, as sails is built on top of both.

How you would approach the solution, really depends on the scale and use of your application/applications. For example; will the same login credentials be used to access multiple applications or a single web application, will the application be available only in an intranet or across the whole WWW.

Regardless of the scenario above, there will next to always be some initial setup required by the user, whether that is an initial sign up with an identity provider or an initial sign up with your application. The sign up form, will not dissappear entirely, rather it will become a one time event.

So let's look at some options and how we might introduce them into an express/sails application/s, I will start with the most basic and work down in difficulty.

**Option 1:**
Make use of the [sails session](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/sessions) store. From your code, you have already started doing this. The logic works something like this:

Your user signs up or logs in for the first time. At this stage you set the users session to be authenticated.

```
// Store user id in the user session
req.session.me = user.id;
req.session.authenticated;
```

You set a policy on all the pages which require authentication. Luckily, sails has already done some of the heavy lifting here by creating a sessionAuth policy in the folder api/policies. To make use of them open the config/policies.js file and add this policy to your protected pages

```
'my_app' : {
        'route_to_protect' : 'sessionAuth'
},
```

Finally, you will want to make this session cookie last a really long time, to do this open config/session.js and edit the cookie maxAge to suit your needs. For example, if you want to force the user to login every 365 days, you might do some like this:

```
// milliseconds * seconds * minutes * hours * days
cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
},
```

The draw back to this option is that your sessions will be lost if the application is restarted and all users will have to log in again.

**Option 2:**
Use a simple third party library like [passwordless](https://passwordless.net). Passwordless offers token-based authentication for express web applications and as sails is built on top of express...

The general jist of passwordless is when a user signs up, you deliver them a link to your application via email, this will log them in and in turn set up there session. Passwordless makes use of mongo as a session store, so you can either install mongo or use something like [mLab](https://mlab.com/) which is a Mongo Database-as-a-Service provider. For a complete run through on using passwordless, take a look at their getting start page [here](https://passwordless.net/getstarted).

Now for the more featureful based options.

**Option 3:**
If you are developing an application that is public facing, making use of [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) with sails is a great option.

Passport is authentication middleware for Node.js. Extremely flexible and modular, Passport can be unobtrusively dropped in to any Express-based web application. A comprehensive set of strategies support authentication using a username and password, Facebook, Twitter, and more.

Passport works with Sails just like it does with Express.

There are already a shed load of guides on setting up passport out in the ether. But a great step-by-step is available [here](http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/) and is also the one referenced by sails in there official documentation [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/policies/sails-passport).

Passport is in all essence an authentication middleware. It allows users to identify themselves based on this authentication, you can develop the correct authorization functionality in your application.

**Option 4:**
Make use of SAML or OAuth. From a development and implementation perspective, these are by far the biggest undertaking out of the options provided.

SAML and OAuth are authorization middleware which refers to rules that determine who is allowed to do what. Both have a very similar setup and make use of an Identity Provider(IdP) and Service Provider(SP), where the IdP represents an online service that authenticates users in the flow and the SP represents an application that relies on a trusted IdP for authentication and authorization.

I am more familiar with SAML, so what follows is with reference to considerations when implementing SAML in a project.

You will first need to register your application (SP) with an IdP. With regards to IdP's, what you choose is based on the scale and requirements of your application, there are free online IdP's like [ZXIDP](http://zxidp.org/index-idp.html) and [SSOCircle](https://www.ssocircle.com/en/portfolio/publicidp/) or if your application required a dedicated IdP you could look at something like [OpenSSO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/opensso-091890.html). You could also consider creating your own Node.js IdP using the [saml-idp package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml-idp).

Integrating SAML into a sails application is not overly difficult. Make use of the [saml2-js package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js).

Once all configured, the logic works something like this.

1. User opens their web-browser and goes to yoururl.
2. To authenticate the user yoururl constructs a SAML Authnrequest, signs, encrypts and encodes it.
3. Then yoururl redirects the user's to the IdP to authenticate.
4. The IdP validates the request, in the first signup/login, the IdP will ask the user to enter their username and password, after that it will use the sessioning and other than the address change in the browser address bar the user will not see much.
5. If the user is successfully authenticated, the IdP generates a SAML token that includes information about the user (username, etc) and redirects them with this token back to yoururl.
6. Finally yoururl verifies the SAML token, extracts the identity information about the user including authorisations and logs them in.